# Why is parseFromString resulting in [object HTMLUnknownElement]?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following lines of code:

```
...

var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
var doc = parser.parseFromString(mattes_get_mattes_xml(), "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
console.log(mattes_get_mattes_xml());
console.log(doc);

...
```

The first output statement, `console.log(mattes_get_mattes_xml());`, results in the following:

```
<Mats><mat><item size='0'><imgsrc>11852997eab43ff5c7b1803692bee608</imgsrc><size>0</size><cpu></cpu><cid>4208</cid><id/></item><fillet index='0'></fillet></mat><mat><item size='0.5'><imgsrc>11852997eab43ff5c7b1803692bee608</imgsrc><size>0.5</size><cpu>12</cpu><cid>4208</cid><id/></item><fillet index='1'></fillet></mat></Mats>
```

The second output statement, `console.log(doc);`, results in the following:
[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong with the first `<cid>` element that it isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: Maybe the DOMParser saw two `<cid>4208</cid>` and it decided they were the same node, so it inserted a reference instead of duplicating the node.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I was passing in the variable cid as well as declaring a new variable cid in this function. I renamed the second variable to something else and it works now.